# method is not called inside another method in JUnit

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I have a method that calls another mehide inside.
Here is my method:

```
    public void unblocUser(BloclistDTO bloclistDTO) {
    blocListRepository.delete(mapper.toModel(bloclistDTO));
      if (blocListRepository.getBlocList(bloclistDTO.getCandidate().getId(), bloclistDTO.getColumnName()).isEmpty()) {
        this.setVisibility(bloclistDTO.getCandidate().getId(), bloclistDTO.getColumnName(), true);
    }  
}
```

I've tested the method setVisibility itself, it works. But, when clling unblocUser it doesn't work ; 
Here is how am testing it:

```
@Test
public void unblocUserLastOne() {
        Company  blockedCompany = new Company (); 
        Candidate  candidate = new Candidate (); 
        candidate.setId(1L); 
        candidate.setPersonalDetailsVisible(false);;
        blockedCompany.setId(2L);
        candidate.setPersonalDetailsVisible(false);
        BloclistDTO bloclist= new BloclistDTO(); 
        bloclist.setBlockedCandidate(null);
        bloclist.setCandidate(candidate);
        bloclist.setBlockedCompany(blockedCompany);
        bloclist.setColumnName("personal_details_visible");   
        bloclist.setId(3L);
        blocListService.unblocUser(bloclist); 
         assertEquals(true, candidate.isPersonalDetailsVisible());   
}
```

I get an error : expected true but was false.
Any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to create a mock object for BlocListRepository class

```
@InjectMocks
BlocListRepository blocListRepository;
```

Then mock the delete method in BlocListRepository class.

```
@Test
public void unblocUserLastOne() {

    Mockito.doNothing().when(blocListRepository).delete(Mockito.any());

    Company  blockedCompany = new Company (); 
    Candidate  candidate = new Candidate (); 
    candidate.setId(1L); 
    candidate.setPersonalDetailsVisible(false);;
    blockedCompany.setId(2L);
    candidate.setPersonalDetailsVisible(false);

    BloclistDTO bloclist= new BloclistDTO(); 
    bloclist.setBlockedCandidate(null);
    bloclist.setCandidate(candidate);
    bloclist.setBlockedCompany(blockedCompany);
    bloclist.setColumnName("personal_details_visible");   
    bloclist.setId(3L);
    blocListService.unblocUser(bloclist); 
    assertEquals(true, candidate.isPersonalDetailsVisible());   
}
```

Comment: I get this error : Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'blocListRepository'! Cause: the type 'BlocListRepository' is an interface.
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.

Comment: try this    BlocListRepository blocListRepository = PowerMockito.mock(BlocListRepository.class)